# Sugestão de edição em wiki de tag e fragmento mostrando "votos"

Tags: bug, layout, edições-sugeridas, wikis-de-tags

Estava vendo uma edição pendente minha para um wiki e fragmento e reparei no texto "*0 votos*" no lado esquerdo, sendo que wikis e fragmentos não recebem votos. O mesmo ocorre para edições já aprovadas e rejeitadas.

[Wiki:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/302518)

[image: edição do wiki de tag exibindo "0 votos"]

[Fragmento:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/302518)

[image: edição do fragmento de tag exibindo "0 votos"]

Comment: Até existem votos sim, [usuários com 5k+ podem votar para aprovar edições em wikis de tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). Se são esses votos que aparecem no print, aí já não tenho certeza.

Comment: Acho que esses votos que você comentou são "Aprovar" e "Rejeitar", pelo menos é o que significa nas [edições de publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). E no momento da print já tinha um "aprovado", mas está com *0 votos*, então acho que é bug por usar o mesmo template de uma publicação (pergunta / resposta).

Comment: Podem ser vários bugs atuando em conjunto. Na base de dados da SE, todos os votos ficam na mesma tabela, e possuem uma marca de tipo (up, down, fechar, aprovar etc).

Comment: Acho que esse problema deveria estar no https://meta.stackexchange.com, pois se de fato é um BUG ou algo que não é claro como funciona é provavel que alguém da staff (funcionários da SO) poderiam ajudar a esclarecer, é que raramente aparecem por aqui.

Comment: Ok, depois de eu ter perdido um tempo escrevendo a pergunta e postando, apaguei porque encontrei uma pergunta exatamente sobre o mesmo assunto hahaha. Em resumo, dois problemas foram citados em [2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146674/818993), um deles foi resolvido e o outro (contagem de votos) ignorado. Nesse ano (2020) criaram [outra pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345251/818993) com a tag `[suporte]` (removeram a tag `[bug]` por ser um "possível bug"), parece meio abandonada, só teve comentários da comunidade, então não sei do andamento disso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema foi resolvido, provavelmente com o [redesign das filas de análise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/818993).

Sugeri alterações em uma tag para confirmar se foram resolvidas mesmo em período de análise, e foram.

[Wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/339892):

[image: edição do wiki de tag sem exibir votos]

[Fragmento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/339893):

[image: edição do fragmento do wiki de tag sem exibir votos]